# Problema al visualizar información desde el front

Tags: java, angular, api, spring-boot

Buen día.
Estoy desarrollando un portafolio web usando Angular y Java con Spring Boot. No logro que se visualice la información que traigo desde la api de Spring. Aunque se que esta llegando porque si puedo ver el mensaje que traigo desde el back en la consola y me devuelve un status 200.
Este es el código del servicio que trae los datos del back:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PorfolioService {
url:string="http://localhost:8080/portfolio";

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }
obtenerDatos(): Observable<any> {

  return this.http.get<any>(this.url+"/about");  
}
}
```

Este es el componente donde espero que se impriman los datos:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PorfolioService } from 'src/app/servicios/porfolio.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private datosPorfolio:PorfolioService) {}
miPorfolio:any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datosPorfolio.obtenerDatos().subscribe(data => {      
      this.miPorfolio = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Intento traer la información de una clase controller. Este es el codigo:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
  @RestController  
 @CrossOrigin (origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {

  @GetMapping ("/portfolio/about")
  @ResponseBody
  public String aboutNombre() {
 return "prueba de conexion al back";
 // return "{ \"text\":\"Prueba de conexion al back\" }"; Tambien intente con este otro return 
  } 
  }
```

Este es el error que me muestra la consola:
[image: Se ve que la información llega]

Cual puede ser la causa?

Comment: El error es claro.. dice que espera un json como respuesta y vos estas devolviendo una cadena... eso queda claro no?

Comment: Dado que es una rest api, no tiene sentido devolver textos... deberías estar devolviendo objetos! Al anotarlo como @RestController spring te hace la transformación de objeto de java a objeto JSON *automágicamente*, pero un string sin más no sabe cómo cojines transformarlo a json (no hay datos suficientes para montar un JSON porque el string no tiene un nombre de atributo!). Además... por favor, no uses `any`. Cada vez que pones `any` en **TYPE**script, el creador de JS mata a dos gatitos. Salvemos los gatitos, usemos tipado! Además, eso te habría ayudado a no tener este problema :)

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la ayuda. En realidad el echo es que no soy desarrollador solo estoy haciendo un curso de Fullstack y se bastante poco de programación y nada de buenas practicas jaja, será cuestión de ir aprendiendo. Logre enviar el objeto en JSON terminando de implementar la lógica completa del lado del back, ósea todas las clases e interfaces (model, service, repository, controller) y con los datos cargados en Mysql.  De nuevo muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás devolviendo una cadena de texto y no un objeto json completo, prueba a usar `ResponseEntity`, te dejo [un manual](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity)

Eso te permitirá fácilmente devolver el `String` como un objeto.